# Как узнать ширину полосы с индикатором батареи?

Tags: android, java

Добрый день. Мне нужно обрезать картинку по размеру видимой области. Ширина равна ширине экрана, а вот высота - высота экрана за вычетом высоты полосы (не знаю названия, которая с часами и зарядом батареи). Как узнать высоту этой полоски?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> полосы (не знаю названия, которая с часами и зарядом батареи)

Называется *status bar*

Размер высоты статус бара содержится в ресурсах оси под идентификатором: `status_bar_height`

```
public int getStatusBarHeight() {
   int result = 0;
   int resourceId = getResources().getIdentifier("status_bar_height", "dimen", "android");
   if (resourceId > 0)
      result = getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(resourceId);
  return result;
}
```

В некоторых прошивках может отсутствовать.